# Is it possible to \include .tex files from other directories?

Tags: include

I want to use the command `\include` to include a `.tex` file which is not in the same directory as the main `.tex` file.

Is this possible? I have not found any information about it, and this:

> \include{/myuser/Desktop/mydir/mytex}

does not work.

Note that I am under Debian Wheezy.

Comment: You should use the universal `/` operator for folder designation, not ``\``.

Comment: No, for security reasons, TeX is disallowed writing in directories above the current one or those specified with an absolute path. Would you like it to write in `/etc`?

Comment: to expand on egreg's answer: relative paths are fine.  So you can do things like `include{chap/one}`.

Comment: @egreg Does that mean I could \include .tex files from directories below the main one by using a relative path? That would do the trick. I am going to try it, thanks.

Comment: Do you actually want to write or just read? On windows I have various bits of code I am working on in a path (code) at the same level as various projects - you can easily input \input{../code/sometexfile} where my project is at the same level as a universal code folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As egreg has pointed out, TeX is disallowed writing in directories above the current one or those specified with an absolute path.

Relative paths are alowed, so we could do it by using

> \include{mydir/mytex}

Provided mydir is located in the same directory as the main .tex file.